# Echo out arrays as links?

Tags: php, html

I would like to take my result from a SQL query, which I got in the form of arrays, and echo these out as the final step in a "search engine". I would also like these arrays to be links, to the pages that I've set up for each information block, that the SQL query collects from my DB.

Something like this:

```
return $rows;
if (count($row > 0) {
foreach $rows as $row {
echo $row;
} }
```

Am I approaching this in the right way, how would I go on from there?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain what I could have done better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing `$rows` holds the information from your database as an `Array`, `$row['link']` contains the link and `$row['name']` the name you could do the following:

```
if(count($rows) > 0){

    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>';
    }

}else{
    echo 'No results found.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the $rows variable merely contans a list of urls, you can tuse the following:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) echo "<a href='$row'>$row</a>";
```

Also you should remove that `return $rows;` from the top of the snipplet in your question, otherwise it will never reach the loop.

Comment: +1, and you should mention the missing `)` causing a syntax error here: `if(count($row > 0){`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit mangled (you have a `return` statement before the rest of the logic, so it'll never get run.  And you don't need the `if` statement.)

But in general, this principle might work; it depends on what your aim is.  Of course, if you're printing these out as HTML, you'll need to embed them in some actual HTML, e.g.:

```
echo "<a href='$row'>Some text</a>";
```